# Is there any dependency of capitalize attribute of TextView and its ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

`ListView` having TextView as its ListItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <com.dexterous.genero15.font.Audiowide_Regular
        android:id="@+id/club_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="70dp"
        android:padding="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`Audiowide_Regular` is child of `AutofitTextView` which is child of `TextView`

and listview having `setOnItemClickListener` on it.

If i removed attribute         `android:capitalize="characters"` from listItem then `onItemClick` works fine else `onItemClick` not executed.

Is there an dependency of `setOnItemClickListener` and         `android:capitalize="characters"` ?

Comment: I think those are pretty unrelated settings.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `android:capitalize="characters"`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you be setting `android:capitalize="characters"` on a `TextView`? Does your custom `TextView` somehow accept user input? Perhaps you confused the attribute with [`android:textAllCaps="true|false`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps).

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal those are all things pointed out in my answer. If it solved your problem, feel free to upvote and accept the answer to indicate to future readers what the solution was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:capitalize):

> If set, specifies that this TextView has a textual input method and should automatically capitalize what the user types.

Since setting this attribute defines an input method for the TextView, it is most likely intercepting the `OnItemClickListener` and instead using some [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener(android.text.method.KeyListener)) event.

If what you were trying to do is force the TextView to display information in all uppercase characters, you can set the [textAllCaps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps) attribute to true.